# Correct password_hash using

Tags: password-hash

I am trying to make my own user-authorization php-script to login users which where created by other php-class (not mine).

So, I try to make hash-string from word *admin* to make it:

```
$2y$10$trJyrB8x2V/hKKeKJvNF0Otz6OqFgisd0fiLc7B1ssHzSvpE0ADYu
```

My PHP version is 5.4.4. And I am trying to code it like this:

```
echo  (password_hash("admin", PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
```

but it outputs nothing.

I found this code in the third-party php-class:

```
public function make($value, array $options = array())
   {
   $cost = isset($options['rounds']) ? $options['rounds'] : $this->rounds;
   $hash = password_hash($value, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => $cost));
   if ($hash === false) {
       throw new \RuntimeException("Bcrypt hashing not supported.");
   }

   return $hash;
}
```

Does anybody know how to use *password_hash* correctly?

Comment: `password_hash` is only available as of php5.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options array probably creates a problem try this:

```
$hash = password_hash($value, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => $cost]);
```

Comment: Please mark answer as solved and click up arrow, for others to see it's an useful answer. And you are welcome.